# Error installing VC++ 2008 Redistributable Runtime

Tags: windows, runtime

Several programs on my Windows10 (Version 20H2 Build 19042.867) machine require the specific VC++2008 runtime version 9.0.30279.5677 x64 to work properly. I tried to install the runtimes several times, but alway ended up with the following error: [Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txr2v.png)

> Error 1935. An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'policy.9.0.Microsoft.VC90.ATL,version='9.0.30729.6161',publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b',processorArchitecture='amd64',type='win32-policy',Please refer to Help and Support for more Information, HRESULT:0x80070057.

Other runtimes of VC++2008 (x86 and x64) did install without any problems.

Is there a workaround to get the runtime mentioned above installed?

Comment: VC++ runtimes are backwards compatible, so you can use a later version. Have you tried using a newer VC++ runtime?

Comment: I was able to install version 9.0.21022. The latest version I could download from Microsoft´s website is 9.0.30729.5677(x64). But this one doesn´t install, giving me the error message above.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed heaps of VC++ runtimes with never a problem.
I have 4 versions installed of the VC++ 2008 Redistributable,
although yours is not one of them.
This is surely an overkill, as developers have the bad habit of including in the
package the version that they used when developing the application

A problem may arise that may block Visual C++ redistributables from superseding
each other, as some apps may specifically bind to an exact version of the
Visual C++ DLLs, to make sure that the app runs exactly as published.

Most apps, however, bind to the latest edition of the same major version,
as it is the default behavior and can benefit from Microsoft's security updates.

My first advice, if you have any version of the VC++ 2008 Redistributable
currently installed, is to try to run the app without installing it.

If you don't have any installed VC++ 2008 Redistributable version,
try to install the
[latest version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336).

If the app still does not run, then this means that it binds itself to this
version specifically, but its installation seems to be corrupted.
I have not found this exact version for download on the internet.

In the case that the problem is with your computer, you may:

- Ensure that the `C:` disk is not almost full
- Try running in CMD as Administrator:

  - `chkdsk`
  - `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
  - [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).